# bundle d.ts without references directive

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I'm building old fashion application without JS modules (yes, global scope). I'm using compiler options `outFile` and `declaration` to bundle all `.ts` sources in single project to single file and single `d.ts` file, which I reference from my other projects.

I started to utilize `@types`, and I moved `node_modules` to root of my projects, so `@types` are [visible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), and automatically loaded. I also set watch & copy for bundled `d.ts` from all of my projects into `node_modules\@types\`, and this further helps me cross load declarations between my projects. Sweet.

Then I included `moment.js` in one of my project and something unpleasant happened. This library has its own declaration file in `node_modules\moment` directory, and `tsc` appends this `d.ts` as `\\\ <references...` directive with explicit path, which, obviously, after copying into other destination, fails to match.

If there would be some options to *append external declarations directly, by copy, not by reference*, into the bundle, that would be great! Is there something like that?

Comment: "I moved node_modules to root of my projects" what do you mean?

Comment: @gilamran you can exchange `library` for `project`, I'm working in Visual Studio (not Code), where projects are common concept. It means folder with code, which you created for some purpose and you works with it as, wel, single project. So "root of my projects " means root of my projects folders.

Comment: This is similar to what's called mono-repo. where one folder holds many projects. You should NOT put the node_modules on the root folder, and leave it on each project as it is. As each project has it own dependencies.

Comment: @gilamran the top `node_modules` contains only `@types` dependencies, so I think it's all-right.

Comment: I've posted an answer, where I detailed how you should structure your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Each project should have its own `node_modules` => dependencies (Including the `@types`).

**This way you will not mix dependencies**. This part is very important as you experienced it yourself.

You should use the `npm link` command to be able to work fast without publishing a new version on every change. read about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Regarding `@types`: TypeScript automatically scans all the `@types`'s sub-folders and auto includes them (Unless you added `types` to the `tsconfig`), meaning that your "global" module should be available to the project that depends on it. read about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

Example multi project structure:

```
 - project1
  - node_modules
     - @types
         - project2
         - moment
         - lodash
  - src
     - main.ts
  - tsconfig.json

 - project2
  - src
     - library.ts
  - tsconfig.json
```

Comment: My problem is just loading declarations during development, for the IDE, and, I do not want to maintain separated `node_modules` with declaration in each and every project folder. I'm just exploiting the feature of typescript's automatic `@types` loading, otherwise, I do not need `node_modules` at all. If I would be able to create single declaration file without `\\\ <references ...` directive in it, then I will be free of all `npm` maintenance and, more importantly, all my colleagues will be also free of all of this `npm` overhead.

Comment: Your problem started when you used `npm` and installed `moment`, if you don't want to use `npm` then you don't have a problem... If you want to use `npm` follow the rules, or you'll have issues...

Comment: What I really need, is build my own `@types` declarations for each of my project and load that declarations in other projects. I'm currently inspecting how to make that real.

Comment: Your way might get it to work somehow... but as mentioned before: you will get into issues if you don't follow the requirements.